# How to properly set up Vite, Express, Tailwind web app

Tags: express, tailwind-css, vite

Scenario: 
I am making a basic web app using Vite & Tailwind. I set up my app as normal installing Vite, and Tailwind, and got everything running fine by testing for Tailwind css on localhost:5500. 
Problem: 
Once I added an Express server to the mix, and it sends the index.html in response to a 'GET' request @ '/', I no longer get the compiled CSS from tailwind. 
Is this an uncommon setup that should be troublesome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could possibly use a `middleware` like `express.static`

Example:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})
```

In this example, the `express.static` middleware is used to serve the `public` directory, which is where the compiled CSS files from Tailwind will be located. Then the express server will send the index.html file in response to a `GET` request at the root `'/'` path.

---

Extra: Alternatively you can also use `Webpack` or `Parcel` , which can automatically handle the process of bundling and serving your CSS files

Comment: I am using Vite, and Vite keeps the index.html file in the project root dir, and upon bundling it compiles everything to an assets folder. This was a source of confusion for me; of where to initially serve my files, e.g. serve the compiled index.html or the one i'm working off of in the root folder. In addition to that I was getting a strict mime type error on my stylesheet links, adding type="text/css" fixed it, assuming this was related to my incorrect directories, but was not. I did end up using express middleware, confusing the issues when the css didnt work...anyway, thanks for your help.