# Tailwind CSS doesn't apply styles when setup with React and Vite

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, vite, postcss

I setup a React project with Vite. I also installed TailwindCSS successfully with no errors in the terminal. I followed all documentation instructions but on trying to use the Tailwind classes from the doc examples, none are working. My final rendered HTML don't reflect the styles I have set on them.

**`vite.config.js`**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import tailwindcss from "tailwindcss"

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  css: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [tailwindcss()],
    }
  }
})
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{js, ts, jsx, tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**index.css**

```
@itailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@tailwind base;
```

**postcss.config.js**

```
export default {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

Here's a repo containing the full project files: [Tailwind Test](https://github.com/mighty-odewumi/tailwind-test)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly set up Vite, Express, Tailwind web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75216812/how-to-properly-set-up-vite-express-tailwind-web-app)

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out that the problem came from the tailwind.config.js file. In the content array, **js** came before **jsx** which was blocking what it was supposed to do.

One thing I don't understand is that I thought since they were listed, Tailwind is supposed to pick the one applicable to it (that is, the **jsx**). Why did I have to clear the **js** in front before it worked?